# In iOS's "Today View," can we show more questions?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-today-view

In the widget, we see one of the featured questions from StackExchange with its logo next to it:

[image: Today View Widget]

Can we give the user a preference on how many questions from the site should show up here? I might want to see 3 or 4 questions instead of just one. I'm sure people with the bigger iPhone 6 Plus might as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be added in 1.6.0.1 for devices running iOS 10.

iOS 10 has a new "Show More" feature exactly this use case.  You'll be able to expand and cycle hot questions.

[image: Screenshot showing expanded today widget in iOS 10]